# Should I write a setter to access class variable for testing?

Tags: python, testing

I have `request_ticker_data` method that uses input ticker string to request data through Yahoo Finance. It appends the ticker to class variable `self.invalid` list if the data could not be accessed. I also have a `reset_invalid` method that resets `invalid` to an empty list.

I want to write a unit test for `reset_invalid` but not sure whether I should assign to `self.invalid` directly or write a setter method just for the purpose of testing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect it would be safer to create a *getter* like `get_invalid_list()`, which returns the current invalid list.

That way you're not creating something that can be used to change the state of your class unnecessarily. If you ship it with a setter, you can guarantee that, at some point, someone will use that setter to cause you grief :-) A getter, on the other hand, will just give them data but will not allow them to affect the state of the object.

To test the getter, you could call:

```
obj.reset_invalid()
obj.request_ticker_data('xyzzy_plugh_twisty_zorkmids') # does *not* exist
x = obj.get_invalid_list()
```

You should then have a list with that invalid code. The next step is then:

```
obj.reset_invalid()
x = obj.get_invalid_list()
```

which should result in an *empty* list being returned. That tests both the actions that happen for an invalid code *and* the ability to reset the list.

Comment: That's what I have right now. I wrote a class of tests for `request_ticker_data` that check for invalid and correct tickers. Should I put the reset method together in that class?

Comment: @Kingle, there's a group of people that think you should only ever test *one* thing in a test. And then there are sane people :-) It all depends on whether the thing you're testing is the `reset_invalid()` function or the "invalid list functionality". I'd probably prefer the latter myself so would put a few (related) checks into a single test. Otherwise, *very* targeted tests tend to require a lot more setup than if you have a mini-suite that sets up as part of the tests.

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense. I'm learning unit testing and assumed that you test exactly one thing with each test. I guess there's no need to go overboard if my tests provide enough coverage.